# Pyqt5 & QML2 deploy on debian/mint (dev - ubuntu)

Tags: qt, dialog, pyqt, qml, freeze

I have pyqt5 application which uses qml2 as frontend. While migrating from developer's (my) machine to another (mint qiana, debian sid) it stucks on importing `QtQuick.Dialogs 1.1`.

Error can be reproduced even on fresh `docker` containers running `debian-sid` image.

My test python script:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtWidgets, QtCore, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtProperty, QCoreApplication, QObject, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtQml import qmlRegisterType, QQmlComponent, QQmlEngine


class CommonQMLWindow():

    def __init__(self, qml_file_name):
        self._engine = QQmlEngine()
        component = QQmlComponent(self._engine)

        # STUCK HERE (LINE BELOW - component.loadUrl)
        component.loadUrl(QUrl(qml_file_name))
        self.qml_window = component.create()

        if self.qml_window is None:
            for error in component.errors():
                print(error.toString())

            exit(1)

from ui import commonqmlwindow
```

Loading:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtWidgets, QtCore, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtProperty, QCoreApplication, QObject, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtQml import qmlRegisterType, QQmlComponent, QQmlEngine


class MainWindow(commonqmlwindow.CommonQMLWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        commonqmlwindow.CommonQMLWindow.__init__(self, 'ui/test.qml')
```

qml file:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.1
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2

import "." as Controls
import "../uihelpers.js" as UIHelpers


TextField {
    id: rootItem

    property bool pickDirectory: false
    property alias pickerTitle: picker.title
    property alias pickerSelectMask: picker.nameFilters
    property alias selectedUrl: picker.fileUrl


    readOnly: true

    FileDialog {
        id: picker

        selectFolder: rootItem.pickDirectory ? true : false
    }
}
```

main.py:

```
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
main_window = mainwindow.MainWindow()
app.exec()
```

All packages are installed (for qml2, python3, pyqt5 and qt5) works well for anything but this.

This behavior happens on `Linux Mint qiana`, `Debian sid`. When I comment import statment (`//import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.1`) it works but I need FileDialog..

Versions:

Qt version: 5.3.2

PyQt version: 5.3.2

Python version: 3.4.2

UPD: it works even on Mac OS X Yosemite but not on debian.

Comment: Can't make sense of the second paragraph - can you please clarify it?

Comment: About `docker` containers?

Comment: Yes, that's the one. Also: do you get any error messages?

Comment: No any error message, just freeze at launching. I've updated question appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is no any known reason of this behavior at this moment. I've created a [bugreport](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-43054) and found kinda workaround-solution of the problem. The problem can be avoided by using `QQmlApplicationEngine` instead of `QQmlEngine` to create qml components. It seems `QQmlEngine` is buggy because these 2 classes do almost the same work.

```
from PyQt5 import QtQml
engine = QtQml.QQmlApplicationEngine()
engine.load(QtCore.QUrl('test.qml'))
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Also I've done some attempts to reproduce the error with C++ code but it seems this behavior is bad of PyQt5's implementation only because it works fine with C++ backend.

Unfortunately I can't see any bug-tracker of `PyQt` project so it may be unfixed for a long time unless the developers will see this answer.